# avoid everytime check for nonnull and nonempty variables at dto in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, isnullorempty

I have following method which updates user data if the data is nonEmpty or nonNull

```
public Users updateUser(Users requestBody) throws AppServiceException {

        Users user = new Users();
        try {

            user = userDAO.getUserByUserId(requestBody.getUserId());

        if (requestBody.getRole() != null && !requestBody.getRole().isEmpty()) {
            user.setRole(requestBody.getRole());
        }

        if (requestBody.getUserName() != null && !requestBody.getUserName().isEmpty()) {
            user.setUserName(requestBody.getUserName());
        }

        if (requestBody.getChannelType() != null && !requestBody.getChannelType().isEmpty()) {
            user.setChannelType(requestBody.getChannelType());
        }

        if (requestBody.getStatus() != null && !requestBody.getStatus().isEmpty()) {
            user.setStatus(requestBody.getStatus());
        }
        if (requestBody.getDevice() != null) {
            user.setDevice(requestBody.getDevice());
        }

        user.setUpdatedDate(new Date());

        user = userDAO.updateUser(user);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AppServiceException(AppServiceException._FAIL_TO_UPDATE);
        }
        return user;
    }
```

I checked the values for nonNull & isEmpty everytime.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache commons lang's [StringUtils.isEmpty(java.lang.String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String))

> Checks if a String is empty ("") or null.

If your code:

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(requestBody.getStatus())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have two class:

```
@Data
class X {
    private String field1;
}

@Data
class Y {
    private String field2;
}
```

define static method

```
static <F, T>void copy(F f, T t, Function<F, String> get, BiConsumer<T, String> set){
    String value = get.apply(f);
    if(value != null && value.isEmpty()){
        set.accept(t, value);
    }

}
```

and use it in your code:

```
    X x = new X();
    Y y = new Y();

    copy(x, y, X::getField1, Y::setField2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this checking logic inside getter methods, i.e

```
public Optional<String> getChannelType() {

    if (channelType.isEmpty() || channelType == null)
        return Optional.empty();
    else
        return Optional.of(channelType);

}
```

Comment: You should check `channelType == null` first. Otherwise a NPE could be thrown on `channelType.isEmpty()`. But you could keep it even simpler using just: `return Optional.ofNullable(channelType).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty());`

Answer (score 0):

If it's just copying between 2 beans with same variable names, then you can use `BeanUtils.copyProperties` to do so.
Here we can say the BeanUtil to copy non null values. So the code will be reduced to 1 lines.

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destination, (.. optional parameter to copy non null value)
```